# Site Template and Master pages

Tags: sharepoint, master-pages

I am a .net developer and want to learn SharePoint. Usualy we use MasterPages to have a constant layout for all or some of the pages. My confusion here is SharePoint uses Site Template and MasterPages which both sounds to do same thing. am I right?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MasterPages and Site templates are absolutelly different thing. Master page is usually layout of some pages. It's same like in ASP.NET.

In Sharepoint you can create some sites in site collection. These sites are created according to site template. When you creating (for example) team site, it's created according to team site template, which is stored in Sharepoint folder on file system. In site templates you can specify which features should be activated when site is created, which features should be activated on site collection scope etc. Also you can specify list, which should be created, modules... And also you can specify default master page which will be used on site.

You can find more informations on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms434313.aspx)

Comment: thank you, 
so a site template can conatin some paes which all use same master page (if it has been defined). and all pages will be rendered with ContentPlaceHolder

Comment: Yes, but precisely site template is just XML definition. In this definition you can specify that you want deploy some file when site is created (can be aspx pages, master pages...) and store them on some place (list). In deployed pages can be specified some custom master page. If you want use this master page also on pages, which will be created by user in Sharepoint you must specify it in site template definition...